# Configuring autoconf 2.69 and wget 1.12 fail

Tags: cygwin, wget, configure, autoconf

I try to build Autoconf and Wget on Windows Xp platform through Cygwin, but when I run the configure script for both packages, errors occur of the same bug:

```
./configure 

configure: configuring for GNU Wget 1.12 

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 

checking whether build environment is sane... yes 

checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p 

checking for gawk... gawk 

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 


checking build system type... configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

And I when I type `./configure --build=i686-pc-cygwin` on the Cygwin console produce errors:

```
./configure --build=i686-pc-cygwin 

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 

checking whether build environment is sane... yes 

checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p 

checking for gawk... gawk 

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 

checking build system type... 

configure: error: invalid value of canonical build
```

Please, what should I do to configure scripts?

Thank you,

Comment: Holy hell! Wget 1.12! That's over 10 years old!! Why are you trying to build such an old version of Wget?

Comment: Because I use an offline version of Cygwin. Can you recommend a version of Wget that works on Windows Xp through Cygwin, please?

Comment: You can manually download the binary packages you need from [a nearby mirror](https://www.cygwin.com/mirrors.html). Note that a package like [wget has dependencies](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/wget.html), so you'll need those too. Of course, if your Cygwin installation is too old, it's possible that everything will need to be upgraded anyway. You're better off using setup-x86.exe on a Windows machine that is online and transferring the downloaded packages (and cygwin1.dll) to your Windows XP machine. Both methods assume the packages and any new Cygwin DLL still work on Windows XP.

Comment: find a more recent config.guess

Comment: MemReflect The problem persists with Wget 1.19.3showing similar errors when running configure script.Please I need your help to compile other packages through installing autoconf and Wget,

Comment: matzeri I had but the package does not run on